# Pass data to another page and submit form on that page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like a button on page1.html. This button will pass data to page2.html which has a form on it, load that data into the form, and submit the form on page2.html. Is this possible? How would it be done? I can't seem to find any examples of this.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because going to a second page and auto-submitting is weird. If you're changing pages, you'd normally want your user to submit a form, or else why go to another page?

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible... but why would you **want** such behaviour? Why not just have your form on `page1.html`?

Comment: It is a unique situation where this feature is something I would like to have. It would fill a form on a webgl application with data the end user doesn't know how to readily find, and I'd like the ability to update this "featured" data without updating the webgl application page every time. So I can feature this data, then change it whenever without having to update the webgl app.

Comment: I guess you'd include the values on the query string when sending the user to `page2.html`, and then in `page2.html` you'd have JavaScript code which checks the query string for values and populates the form with those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PHP's Post method:

From originating page1.php page:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="MyName" id="MyId" value="MyVal">
     <input type="submit" value="Post to page2">
</form>
```

In receiving page2.php page:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST)) : ?> // Check for Post data
    <script>
       document.getElementById("MyId").value = '<?php echo $_POST["MyName"]; ?>'; //update form on page2.php by field ID
       document.getElementById('FormToSubmit').click();
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Of course the best thing to do is to use a backend... but I guess you wouldnt be asking if you had that option.

one thing you can do is use the anchor in the URI, like: `/page2#?field=value&fld=val`

Then on page load, check for an anchor tag and process it:

```
$(function(){
  let hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
})
```

Here's a plunkr to get you off the ground: https://plnkr.co/edit/u9fPGFZedXGmKbbdXVvy?p=preview

So once you have the `hash` you would parse it to JSON and configure your form with it.

It isn't obvious that it works because of how these fiddle-like sites operate. But it does work! To check it out, open the preview in separate window mode, and copy the url, open that url in a new tab, and add a sample hash on it, and press enter so it takes. then reload the page.

Comment: I do have php available to me on the site. The page1.html is coming from a drupal page, so I can use php no sweat. The webgl app is an html document.

Comment: Then skip the bulk of my answer and send the data from page1 to the server. Have the form redirect to page2.. then on page 2, on page load query the server to see if the current session has form variables and if so, add them (like, w/ ajax).

Ps, you should change your post to include PHP in the tags if you want a non-javascript answer.

Comment: That is a tad bit above my head, could you provide a simple example of that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not really a php guy, I could tell you with a different framework. Change your tags to attract php developers to answer. :) g/l

Comment: I wasn't sure which approach to use, php was just an option. I have updated the tags. I'm okay with any solution that works...

Comment: My solution would work.. but it's really a hack. PHP is the right way. I wish you well in your search.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can simply add (target="_blank") to form tag and you can get data in specific action page
 <form action="test.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="test" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```